# How to input legend in figure with one variable?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, legend

I have a variable x, whose value is

```
x=0:3:30;
```

I want to input a legend as
[image: fig]

My code is like

```
x = 0:3:30;
figure(1); hold on; grid on;
for i=1:length(Var)
    plot(f1(val(x)));
end
legend('input 0', 'input 3', ..........)
figure(2); hold on; grid on;
for i=1:length(Var)
    plot(f2(val(x)));
end
legend('input 0', 'input 3', ..........)
figure(3); hold on; grid on;
for i=1:length(Var)
    plot(f3(val(x)));
end
legend('input 0', 'input 3', ..........)
```

Is there any method to input legend easily?

When I change x, I have to change all lenged inputs... its so bad... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a cell array of strings, and pass that to `legend`. I just came up with this bit of code to generate your legend strings. It looks a little clunky, but it works.

```
s = split(sprintf('input %d\n',x'),char(10));
legend(s{1:end-1})
```

`sprintf` applies the formatter `'input %d\n'` to each value in `x`. That creates a string with legend entries separated by newlines (`'\n'` equal to `char(10)`). `split` splits the string at the newlines. But because the string ends with a newline, `split` creates an empty string as the last element of the output. `s` is a cell array:

```
s =
  12×1 cell array
    'input 0'
    'input 3'
    'input 6'
    'input 9'
    'input 12'
    'input 15'
    'input 18'
    'input 21'
    'input 24'
    'input 27'
    'input 30'
    ''
```

`s{1:end-1}` returns all strings but the last one.

Comment: Ah, legend function allows a cell argument!! thank you.